# Can you set dynamic messageGroupId using EventBridge and FIFO SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-event-bridge

Can you set dynamically messageGroupId from the payload content when you set SQS FIFO as a target for your EventBridge rule?

From the current setup I see that it can be only a hardcoded value.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to have a lambda function in between to set `messageGroupId`:

```
EventBridige --> Lambda --> SQS FIFO.
```